# Output of chrome.tabs.executeScript is different from that of console

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-console

I am writing a chrome extension using `chrome.tabs.executeScript`to get the attribute of a tag in html but I notice a difference between the result returned by this function and the result in the console.

```
var scriptToExec = 'document.getElementsByTagName("video")';
chrome.tabs.executeScript({ code: scriptToExec }, getResult);

function getResult(resultArray) {
if (resultArray.length > 0) {
    console.log(resultArray);
    //console.log(resultArray[0].getAttribute("name"));
};}
```

My test page has one video tag but I think I do not get the expected object in `getResult`

Could anyone tell me what am I missing pls?

[Extension popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WAbU.png)
[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNhck.png)

Comment: `popup` doesn't have access to a webpage, you should use `content-script`

Comment: You can't message DOM elements, everything gets stripped. Extract the attributes you need and pass a normal object.

Comment: Thanks guys, especially @wOxxOm it is better to extract the attributes and pass it